# Object locations don't change in animation

Tags: python, animation, rigging

I have a rigged animation object where I want to track the global position of different parts, however their location does not update in frame to frame.

e.g. in this Rat model, I want to track the position of the nose

There are many similar titled posts, I've tried many of their approaches but to no success

[image]

### Structure

It's hard to show the complete structure, but for example the "Nose" part exists
[image]

### Object View

[image]

### Edit View

[image]

### Code

My current script for checking the position looks like the following (I've tried many variations based on anything I can find online)

It's only purpose is to see if any of the objects change positions. My end goal is to be able to specify specific objects or vertices and find their global position in the frame

```py
import bpy 
import numpy as np

from pathlib import Path 


# SETUP 
#----------------------------------------------------------
output_path = Path("~/Desktop/blender-test").expanduser()
output_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

# ANIMATION 
#----------------------------------------------------------
scene = bpy.context.scene
context = bpy.context

bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all()
positions = {}
def frame_change_post(scene):
    scene.render.filepath = str(output_path / f"render_{i:04}.png")

    print("Number of objects in the scene:", len(scene.objects))        
    for obj in scene.objects:
        if obj.type != 'MESH':
            continue

        object_name = obj.name
        position = np.array(obj.matrix_world.translation)

        if positions.get(object_name) is None:
            positions[object_name] = position

        elif not np.array_equal(positions[object_name], position):
            print("Position changed!", object_name, positions[object_name], '->', position)
            positions[object_name] = position

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(frame_change_post)

for i in range(1, 10):
    print(f"Rendering frame {i}")
    scene.frame_set(i)
    context.view_layer.update()
```

And just in case its relevant, I'm launching the script from the terminal `./blender ~/test.blend --background --python ~/repos/USRA_MouseAnimation/test_movement.py`

Comment: The mesh you're showing in the outliner is probably a bone shape, which doesn't change its transform.  Your best bet here, IMO, is to create an empty, parent it with vertex(triangle) to three selected vertices in the rat mesh, and then read the position of that empty.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, would every mesh be a bone shape though? I'm loop over all meshes to see if any change

Comment: No, not every mesh is a bone shape.  But the position you're interested in is probably the result of deformation (armature) rather than transformation (object.)

Comment: It worked!!! I would accept this as an answer.